# workaround for bitbucket requiring email address to merge a pull request

Tags: email, merge, ldap, bitbucket, pull-request

We've migrated from a different control tool to bitbucket and seem to be encountering growing pains.

Our system is managed by LDAP and it seems that bitbucket requires an email address in order to merge a pull request.  However, the user directory account (LDAP) is read only for the development and Bitbucket admin folks like myself (it seems only SAs have write access to LDAP).

So, it seems we're stuck at this point: can't do a merge because user doesn't have an email address and we can't modify the user accounts as they're read only.

Poor system set up and poor tool design decision aside, my question is:  is there a workaround to this Bitbucket requirement of requiring an email address to merge a pull request?

The Atlassian [solution](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/unable-to-merge-a-pull-request-with-the-ldap-user-account-due-to-missing-email-address-in-bitbucket-server-1115662421.html) (biting my tongue here) is to add the email address to LDAP user profile, which will require a degree of effort by the SAs to add email addresses.

The other alternative is to give the admin access, which just isn't a good idea.